# Shiny DT hide rows with same column value and a button to hide/show the rows

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

I would like to use a button to show/hide the rows of the DT table that have the same value in a column but retain one of the rows so it can be selected. I want this to be a client side operation as i would like continue to use the custom filter extension on all rows.

I suspect there is a JavaScript JS() function or callback that can be integrated with shiny R to manage this but do not have the expertise required to make it happen.

for example in the case below: we would hid all rows where there duplicate species but each species would have one row.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(DTOutput('tbl')),

  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = renderDT(
      iris, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
    )
  }
)
```

Thanks,

Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way. The idea is to add a new column

```r
c("setosa", "", "", ..., "virginica", "", "", ..., "versicolor", "", "", ...)
```

to the dataframe, and then to search for setosa, virginica or versicolor in this column on clicking the button. Of course this column is hidden to the user.

```r
library(DT)
library(shiny)

dat <- iris
column <- "Species"
groups <- split(as.character(dat[[column]]), dat[[column]]) # use as.character 
                                                            # because it's factor
for(g in names(groups)) {
  group <- groups[[g]]
  groups[[g]][tail(seq_along(group), -1L)] <- ""
}

newColumn <- unsplit(groups, dat[[column]])
dat <- cbind(dat, newColumn)
index <- ncol(dat) # index of newColumn; subtract 1 if you don't show 
                   # row names in the DT table

levels <- names(groups)
regex <- paste0("(", paste0(levels, collapse = "|"), ")")
callback <- c(
  "var flag = true;",
  sprintf("var regex = '%s';", regex),
  sprintf("var j = %d;", index),
  "$('#btn').on('click', function() {",
  "  if(flag) {",
  "    table.columns(j).search(regex, true, false).draw();",
  "  } else {",
  "    table.columns(j).search('').draw();",
  "  }",
  "  flag = !flag;",
  "});"
)

dtable <- datatable(
  dat, 
  callback = JS(callback),
  options = list(
    columnDefs = list(
      list(targets = index, visible = FALSE)
    )
  )
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  actionButton("btn", "Hide/show"),
  br(),
  DTOutput("tbl")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output[["tbl"]] <- renderDT(
    dtable
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: ooooo, this is super clever! i will give it a try and report back :) Thank you!!

Comment: Glad to help @A-A-ron. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it works. It took me a valuable time.